# chown $www-data results in invalid option -- d

Tags: command-line, bash, chown

Trying to set up a lamp development environment by following this guide: https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/lamp/how-to-install-a-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-18-04/.

Trouble starts at the virtual hosts section, step #4, I subbed out the example.com to deckdev.local, so the final command should be

```
sudo chown -R $www-data:$www-data /var/www/html/deckdev.local/public_html
```

which produces the following output

```
chown: invalid option -- 'd'
Try 'chown --help' for more information.
```

I set out to google and discovered this forum thread: https://www.linode.com/community/questions/20208/chown-invalid-option-d which the user jyoo suggests that using the variable names $www-data:$www-data is somehow causing the command parser to misinterpret. I'm leaning towards agreeing with this assestment, problem is no solution was posted on those forums in over two months now.

I personally don't see what's 'wrong' it myself, anyone else able to help unravel this mystery? It's been a little while since I last flexed my linux muscles.

Comment: Do you actually have a variable $www-data?

Comment: `-` is not part of a variable, so the variable ends after `www`, and no, that variable seems empty. See my answer.

Comment: I think they meant to use a variable _name_ `www-data`, which of course is an invalid name in the first place. The description is clearly suggestive of this being meant a placeholder to be replaced by the actual desired username (because the _actual_ user `www-data` is only the right choice on Debian/Ubuntu ... but not necessarily elsewhere ... but then this is a tutorial for Ubuntu). Still really screws up the instructions for those who don't know this sort of stuff (about their Shell) up front.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$www` is an empty variable, so chown sees the following:

```
sudo chown -R -data:-data
```

`-data` or rather `-d` is then interpreted as option.

it should be:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/public_html
```

That seems wrong in that tutorial.